# CSS messing up in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, css

So I have an update panel.

The css for it is as follows

```
#<%=mypanel.ClientID%> 
{
    border-style:inset;
    border-color: #724229;
    background-color: #AD816B;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So this works. Inside of the update panel I also have a scrollbar. It works fine when I load the page but for some reason when something updates inside the panel the css on the scrollbar messes up.

(Normal bar)
[image: How it looks before update]

(after update)
[image: After the update]

I can't figure out why it is doing this. Looked up why it would be doing this but haven't found anything, only on Jquery but it is not using jquery it's all css.

update panel html

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" class="notifications" UpdateMode="Conditional"
            ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="mCustomScrollbar content3 fluid light">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                Action
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 55%">
                                Description
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 30%">
                                Date Added
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you post the html for your update panel? Also, is UpdateMode="Conditional" for the update panel?

Comment: Added the html of it

Comment: Try with UpdateMode="Always".

Comment: Tried Always but then the information doesn't even show up in the update panel.

Comment: Try to declare your update panel as inline `<asp:UpdatePanel RenderMode="Inline"` or `UpdatePanel1.RenderMode = RenderMode.Inline`

Comment: CSS with update panel is not a good idea. Put an `asp:Panel` around the update panel and set its `CssClass='notifications'`. so the update panel is inside the asp:Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the update panel with an asp Panel control as in code below  and add CSS styling to asp Panel control and not to UpdatePanel.

You should not apply CSS to update panel. For this reason, it does not have a property of `CssClass` unlike other web controls.

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server" 
          CssClass ="notifications mCustomScrollbar content3 fluid light">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional"
        ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 15%">
                            Action
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 55%">
                            Description
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 30%">
                            Date Added
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: The css for the update panel works fine even after the update. It just messes up the mcustomscrollbar when an update is called and the panel refreshes.

Comment: Did you try with code I mentioned? You can also move those div  CSS classes to the asp Panel control.

Comment: Use following for asp Panel control: `CssClass='notifications mCustomScrollbar content3 fluid light'`

Comment: I have edited the code snippet so all CSS styles are transfered to the asp Panel control.

Comment: You could also use a wrapping div around the update panel instead of asp Panel. Just replace the markup of asp Panel with that of a div.